# how to select column which is not part of distinct clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a table such as

```
Item    Pno   Code  qty

item1   pn1    1     3
item1   pn2    1     3
item1   pn2    2     2
item2   pn1    1     4
item2   pn3    1     5
item3   pn2    1     3
```

I want to select only the rows which have distinct Item, Code and qty. If Item and code are same than the row with Max(qty) should get selected.

Using the following query:

```
select x.item,pno,x.code,qty from @temp t  join 
(select item,code,max(qty) as quantity from @temp
group by item, code) x on t.item = x.item and t.code = x.code and t.qty = x.quantity
order by item,pno
```

I get:

```
item1   pn1  1   3
item1   pn2  1   3
item1   pn2  2   2
item2   pn3  1   5
item3   pn2  1   3
```

But what i actually want is select only distinct rows based on (item,code,qty)

```
item1   pn1  1   3
item1   pn2  2   2
item2   pn3  1   5
item3   pn2  1   3
```

How can i distinctly select row based on (item,code,qty) irrespective of what Pno comes in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
select * 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item,pno,code ORDER BY qty DESC)rn
from @temp)
SELECT item,pno,code, qty
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you want to say PARTITION BY item,qt,code instead of PARTITION BY item,pno,code